# Control line printing in Terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal

When we use to print a long string through a program in Terminal it printed on multiple lines. I need to print it only in one line through scrolling like in notepad (Windows).
I need a code in c++ language to print in one line until I pass an endline statement.

I want to print in an single line until I use endline statement.
for e.g.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
       cout<<i;
       if(i==50){
          cout<<endl;
       }
   }
}
```

If I run the above code as cpp program then it will print like

```
1234567891011121314151617181920212223.........................
...50
515253.........................
...9899
```

But I want it to be printed in just two lines like

```
1234....................484950
515253..................979899
```

Comment: The question is unclear. The code you included does print in one line until the `endl`.

Comment: perhaps you want to adjust the line width of the terminal you are using

Comment: [It does print two lines](https://godbolt.org/z/93xE186aP).

Comment: what you see as "two lines" in your terminal is actually just a single line wrapped around so it can be displayed.

Comment: if you want to be in better control of where exactly stuff is printed you can take a look at ncurses. The line width of your terminal is not what you can adjust from within your c++ code (at least not in a simple portable way)

Comment: What is the actual underlying issue you are trying to solve? "I need to print it only in one line through scrolling like in notepad" why?

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are planning to do with these long lines. In Notepad you can go back to the line and scroll around to see different parts of it. What do you want to do with the terminal?

Comment: If you redirect the output to a text file and look at it in a text editor you will see that there's just the two lines. I have never encountered a terminal emulator where you can disable line-wrapping. (You can do it by running a shell in e.g. Emacs, but that's not a terminal emulator...)

Comment: If you change the output statement to `cout<<(i%10);`, all 50 digits will fit on one line. The code currently prints up to 100 digits on a line but your terminal most likely supports 80 characters per line. Alternatively, you can change the if-statement to `if((i%36)==0)`, which should give one line of 62 characters, one line of 72 characters and one line of 56 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints exactly as many lines as you wanted. The problem you have encountered is that it is being displayed on multiple lines. But that's just how your terminal or program displays it.

If you are using a Gnome Terminal, then this is how you can increase its line size: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/app-terminal-sizes.html.en

It's important that you will know that it's not your problem but the displaying program that created the illusion of more lines than needed.